# CSS padding added to height/width for <input type='submit'>

Tags: html, css

If this question has been asked, I apologize, but I couldn't find the exact same question. As W3schools says, *The height property does not include padding, borders, or margins!* [(link)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_height.asp). So here's a simple style declaration:

```
input {
  width:180px;
  height:18px;
  padding:7px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

and here's html:

```
<input type='text' name='text' value='194px by 32px' /><br  />
<input type='submit' name='button' id='button' value='180px by 18px' />
```

The text field is 194px by 32px as expected, but the submit button is 180px by 18px. Obviously, I can just increase the height & width of the button by twice the padding, but I want to understand why there's a discrepancy. I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RRf5A/. Thanks for your help. FYI, I already tried `<button>` instead of input submit, and `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Firefox and Safari do not normally display padding on standard buttons, so if you're using one of those browsers, the padding will not be applied.  I believe Internet Explorer does apply some effect from padding (not sure if it works out perfectly though)

Comment: @jqueryrocks, the jsfiddle looks the same in IE7, IE8, Safari, and Firefox, so it's not an IE issue at least ;-)

Comment: Not all w3schools says are correct. Why? see it here [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) To help your further understanding about height/width. See it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html)

Comment: I know w3schools is not authoritative, but if you google a question about html or css, it keeps coming up, so I included the quote so readers would know I at least googled before asking here. :) & Thanks for an interesting link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get around this by adding `box-sizing: content-box;` to input elements of the type submit. Rather than go into detail myself I'll just send you along to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html. However, it's not currently supported all across the board so you might find it better for cross-browser compatibility to specifically declare different heights and paddings for submission buttons.