# Try to align a span and an input

Tags: css, input, html

I have two buttons, one implemented as an input, the other as a span. They are put side by side with:

```
{ display:inline-block; }
```

The buttons are rendered from a customized tag and a class name is added dynamically in jsp. In css, there are some definition for shadow, for background gradient, for padding, and for font. They do use some CSS3 like border-radius.

But in Firefox, the height of the span button is 18 while the input 20. Interestingly, the height of them in IE 8 are both 25px, why?

Now I need them to be of the same height and aligned horizontally.

Update:
Now I have those two buttons in jsfiddle. Use height:22px; and vertical-align:top; won't help much.

http://jsfiddle.net/gBeCP/

Comment: Please provide your html and css code for these elements.  Creating a JSfiddle is even more helpful.

Comment: Post your code or a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) if you'd like help please, right now we'd all just be guessing.

Comment: They are different between browsers because each browser has it's own default style sheet. Please provide code or a jsfiddle to allow us to help you.

Comment: Please show you HTML and css, Even better if you can make fiddle for these problems.

Comment: Edit the question. Not sure how to use jsfiddle with jsp.

Answer (score 8):

Try setting the `vertical-align:top` on the `input` tag. I recommend specifically setting the dimensions in `px` as this will prevent the browser from applying defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it done.

Answer in this page indicates that FF treats the padding differently in submit type of input and a span. [CSS padding added to height/width for <input type='submit'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079359/css-padding-added-to-height-width-for-input-type-submit)

My solution is to set a min-height of both input and span, then use vertical-align:middle; to have them aligned. Finally play around the padding number to have the text on the buttons aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's different is because each browser has its own default styles so they will vary... just like javascript varies dramatically.

Have you ever thought about actually setting some `height` on the elements that you want to be the same height?

maybe

```
span, input[type="button"] {
    height: 25px;
}
```

Or more specifically if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is the following two lines (vendor-prefixes removed for brevity):

```
.tranCoreButton {
    /* I couldn't be bothered to read through the rest of the CSS, or the
       in-line CSS; seriously: *minimal* reproductive demo, please... */
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gBeCP/4/).